# Lower bounds for linear satisfiability problem

Tags: cg.comp-geom, lower-bounds, algebraic-complexity

In [SODA 1995](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=313772), Jeff Erickson showed lower bounds for linear satisfiability (checking if a some $r$-subset of $n$ real numbers satisfies a linear equation on $r$ variables). The proof method uses infinitesimals and Tarski's [transfer principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_principle).

Could someone explain the intuition behind the route taken to prove this bound ? What is the difficulty in coming up with a direct proof like this: "Given a decision tree which takes real numbers, here's how we can construct an adversarial input" ?

Comment: I assume you refer to this document: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=313772

Comment: edited appropriately

Comment: Yes, that's the paper I'm referring to. 

@suresh thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I *strongly* suggest reading the more recent [followup paper by Ailon and Chazelle](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1059513.1059515), which avoids the whole infinitesimal issue entirely.  If you want to stick with my paper, please read the journal version ([Chicago J Theoretical Computer Science 1999](http://cjtcs.cs.uchicago.edu/articles/1999/8/contents.html)).  The SODA version has a major bug in Section 5, and (I think) the journal version explains the main proof much more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the main argument **is** to construct a decision tree and design adversarial input, but there are technical issues with doing this that the infinitesimals avoid. Look at the discussion at the bottom of page 2 first column, and continuing on, which explains this fairly clearly.